# How to get only one record of mutil-dimentional numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a NumPy array as below:

```
X_test.shape
(281,31)
```

I want to get only one record, like:

```
(1,31)
```

How to do it. I am just confused with this.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the `i`th record you can simply index the array:

```py
>>> a = np.random.uniform(size=(281, 31))
>>> a[0]
array([0.62206388, 0.18465268, 0.4233836 , 0.57423524, 0.36190045,
       0.76147936, 0.41142228, 0.16290774, 0.82542559, 0.47262985,
       0.09001842, 0.10263359, 0.38345497, 0.43002741, 0.70323527,
       0.63701071, 0.66322047, 0.46448535, 0.9096295 , 0.80376   ,
       0.54657927, 0.04092028, 0.39676549, 0.49083615, 0.61355298,
       0.21294675, 0.02623933, 0.77223842, 0.26499826, 0.19099018,
       0.45910928])
```

That projects down a dimension though, you can select a slice from `i` to `i+1` to maintain the shape:

```py
>>> a[0:1].shape
(1, 31)
```

If you want an aggregate (e.g. the mean) you can do that as well:

```py
>>> np.mean(a, axis=0)
array([0.46519408, 0.50905068, 0.48498656, 0.49834304, 0.47234612,
       0.51072259, 0.49480418, 0.49348945, 0.5109925 , 0.51813874,
       0.51070899, 0.51457235, 0.50620445, 0.48836886, 0.51032794,
       0.50602566, 0.49622982, 0.49626908, 0.50378099, 0.50709956,
       0.46976559, 0.49622044, 0.49604021, 0.47769351, 0.50123188,
       0.48577959, 0.50971952, 0.5049957 , 0.50583021, 0.5054457 ,
       0.49326958])
```

Comment: Without downing the dimension, this helped me, X_text[0:1]. Thank you so much.